# Oledb connection in visual basic function call

Tags: database, function, plsql

please explain line by line what this particular code which is being used in a button click to store 3 variables is doing?

```
OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT_DEPT", con);
 Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 Cmd.Parameters.Add("PRETURN", OleDbType.VarChar, 30).Direction =ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
 Cmd.Parameters.Add("PDEPTNO", OleDbType.SmallInt, 30).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
Cmd.Parameters["PDEPTNO"].Value = txtDeptno.Text.ToString(); 

Cmd.Parameters.Add("PDNAME", OleDbType.VarChar, 30).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
Cmd.Parameters["PDNAME"].Value = txtDName.Text.ToString();
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 String Str = Convert.ToString(Cmd.Parameters["PRETURN"].Value);
 MessageBox.Show(Str);
```

Comment: It looks like the actual (stored) procedure you use is not in your post. This makes it difficult to impossible to explain this

Comment: It is calling a stored procedure called, "INSERT_DEPT" and passing in a bunch of parameter values, then returning the result to show in a message box.  Go google "OleDBCommand" to read the reference documentation.  This pretty basic stuff you can find many references on the Internet.